# Grails - How to create with model constraints a drop down list for representing belongsTo?

Tags: grails

I'm learning grails, and I have a problem.

I have 2 classes, lets say:

```
    class Book {

      String name
      String description
      static belongsTo = Category
      Category category

      static constraints = {
           name(nullable:false, blank:false)
               description(nullable:true, maxSize:5000)
      }

   class Category {

      String name
      static hasMany = [books:Book]
      Set books
      static constraints = {
              name(nullable:false, blank:false)
      }

      String toString(){
              this.name
      }
   }
```

When I create a book I want to see a drop down list with all the categories name. 
If I don't select a category than I shouldn't be able to create that book.
If there are no categories in the database than I shouldn't be able to create a book,
until I create and select a category.

Is possible for this features to be generated (with grails generate-all) from the domain classes if I have the right constraints and fields? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could be off here, but I think the format of your belongsTo statement is incorrect.  In the examples I've seen and classes I've used it's been:

```
static belongsTo = [category:Category]
```

Then I believe you also need to have the Category set to nullable:false

```
static constraints = {
           name(nullable:false, blank:false)
           description(nullable:true, maxSize:5000)
           category(nullable:false)
      }
```

This should at least generate the dropdown on the view and disallow creating a Book without a Category.

Comment: It works, thank you!
It was so obvious, foolish of me to miss it.